# how to prevent ratelimiterror exchangelib python

Tags: python, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Im pulling daily all the emails from some 8 different postboxes via exchangelib. I was using it the whole week but now the code seems to be throttled by the exchangeserver as the error below gets thrown out while its trying to grab the first email. So I want to learn how to handle it and dont get throttled anymore.  I already implemented one retry policy

```py
credentials = Credentials(username='username', password='password')
config = Configuration(retry_policy=FaultTolerance(max_wait=600), credentials=credentials)
```

for that im using following code:

```py
while True:
    try:
        for shared_postbox in tqdm(shared_postboxes):

            account = Account(shared_postbox, credentials=credentials, config = config, autodiscover=True)
            top_folder = account.root
            email_folders = [f for f in top_folder.walk() if isinstance(f, Messages)]

            for folder in tqdm(email_folders):
                #added item_class in filter and removed order by
                #for m in folder.all().only('text_body', 'datetime_received', "sender").filter(datetime_received__range=(start_of_month,end_of_month), sender__exists=True):
                #when since statement is needed
                for m in folder.all().only('text_body', 'datetime_received', "sender").filter(datetime_received__gt=midnight, sender__exists=True):

                    try: 
                        senderdomain = ExtractingDomain(m.sender.email_address)
                        senderdomains.append(senderdomain)

                    except:
                        print("could not extract domain")

                    else:
                        if senderdomain in domains_of_interest: 

                            postboxname = account.identity.primary_smtp_address
                            body = m.text_body
                            emails.append(body)
                            sender.append(senderdomain)
                            postbox.append(postboxname)
                            received.append(m.datetime_received)
                        #else:
                        #   print("nicht in domains of interest")

            account.protocol.close()
    except RateLimitError as e:
        time.sleep(60)
```

following error code i get:

```py
RateLimitError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 77>()
     81 account = Account(shared_postbox, credentials=credentials, config = config, autodiscover=True)
---> 82 top_folder = account.root
     83 email_folders = [f for f in top_folder.walk() if isinstance(f, Messages)]

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\cached_property.py:74, in threaded_cached_property.__get__(self, obj, cls)
     72 except KeyError:
     73     # if not, do the calculation and release the lock
---> 74     return obj_dict.setdefault(name, self.func(obj))

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py:349, in Account.root(self)
    347 @threaded_cached_property
    348 def root(self):
--> 349     return Root.get_distinguished(account=self)

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\roots.py:114, in RootOfHierarchy.get_distinguished(cls, account)
    113 try:
--> 114     return cls.resolve(
    115         account=account, folder=cls(account=account, name=cls.DISTINGUISHED_FOLDER_ID, is_distinguished=True)
    116     )
    117 except MISSING_FOLDER_ERRORS:

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\base.py:512, in BaseFolder.resolve(cls, account, folder)
    509 @classmethod
    510 def resolve(cls, account, folder):
    511     # Resolve a single folder
--> 512     folders = list(FolderCollection(account=account, folders=[folder]).resolve())
    513     if not folders:

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\collections.py:335, in FolderCollection.resolve(self)
    334 additional_fields = self.get_folder_fields(target_cls=self._get_target_cls())
--> 335 yield from self.__class__(account=self.account, folders=resolveable_folders).get_folders(
    336     additional_fields=additional_fields
    337 )

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\collections.py:403, in FolderCollection.get_folders(self, additional_fields)
    399 additional_fields.update(
    400     (FieldPath(field=BaseFolder.get_field_by_fieldname(f)) for f in self.REQUIRED_FOLDER_FIELDS)
    401 )
--> 403 yield from GetFolder(account=self.account).call(
    404     folders=self.folders,
    405     additional_fields=additional_fields,
    406     shape=ID_ONLY,
    407 )

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\get_folder.py:43, in GetFolder._elems_to_objs(self, elems)
     42 def _elems_to_objs(self, elems):
---> 43     for folder, elem in zip(self.folders, elems):
     44         if isinstance(elem, Exception):

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py:246, in EWSService._chunked_get_elements(self, payload_func, items, **kwargs)
    245 log.debug("Processing chunk %s containing %s items", i, len(chunk))
--> 246 yield from self._get_elements(payload=payload_func(chunk, **kwargs))

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py:266, in EWSService._get_elements(self, payload)
    263 try:
    264     # Create a generator over the response elements so exceptions in response elements are also raised
    265     # here and can be handled.
--> 266     yield from self._response_generator(payload=payload)
    267     return

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py:228, in EWSService._response_generator(self, payload)
    223 """Send the payload to the server, and return the response.
    224 
    225 :param payload: payload as an XML object
    226 :return: the response, as XML objects
    227 """
--> 228 response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
    229 if self.supports_paging:

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py:343, in EWSService._get_response_xml(self, payload, **parse_opts)
    342 log.debug("Trying API version %s", api_version)
--> 343 r = self._get_response(payload=payload, api_version=api_version)
    344 if self.streaming:
    345     # Let 'requests' decode raw data automatically

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services\common.py:298, in EWSService._get_response(self, payload, api_version)
    297 session = self.protocol.get_session()
--> 298 r, session = post_ratelimited(
    299     protocol=self.protocol,
    300     session=session,
    301     url=self.protocol.service_endpoint,
    302     headers=self._extra_headers(session),
    303     data=wrap(
    304         content=payload,
    305         api_version=api_version,
    306         account_to_impersonate=self._account_to_impersonate,
    307         timezone=self._timezone,
    308     ),
    309     stream=self.streaming,
    310     timeout=self.timeout or self.protocol.TIMEOUT,
    311 )
    312 self._handle_response_cookies(session)

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\util.py:880, in post_ratelimited(protocol, session, url, headers, data, allow_redirects, stream, timeout)
    879 total_wait = time.monotonic() - t_start
--> 880 if protocol.retry_policy.may_retry_on_error(response=r, wait=total_wait):
    881     r.close()  # Release memory

File ~\.conda\envs\python383\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\protocol.py:780, in FaultTolerance.may_retry_on_error(self, response, wait)
    778 if wait > self.max_wait:
    779     # We lost patience. Session is cleaned up in outer loop
--> 780     raise RateLimitError(
    781         "Max timeout reached", url=response.url, status_code=response.status_code, total_wait=wait
    782     )
    783 if response.status_code == 401:
    784     # EWS sometimes throws 401's when it wants us to throttle connections. OK to retry.

RateLimitError: Max timeout reached (gave up after 634.031 seconds. URL https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx returned status code 401)
```

When I looked into it, I saw that exchangelib has a function to handle the throttle policy but I don't know to implement it. could the function

```py
def post_ratelimited(protocol, session, url, headers, data, stream=False, timeout=None)
```

help me in this case? I found this function in their [documentation](https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/exchangelib/util.html).

Answer (score 0):

You defined a policy the tells exchangelib to retry up to 600 seconds. The code threw an exception after waiting for more than 600 seconds. That's how it's supposed to work.

If you want the code to retry for a longer period, then increase the `max_wait` value.

Comment: But it goes directly into the retry policy without grabbing even one email. Beforehand it was working for one week everyday once a day without any problem. therefore it is using the retry policy because it doesn't get a response from the postboxes. and i estimate i dont get one as my account got throttled.

Comment: Ok, then possibly something else is going on instead. Try removing the retry policy and see what error pops up - it may be a login issue if the server has disabled Basic auth or your credentials are no longer correct. Otherwise, try debugging this with your Exchange admins.

Answer (score 0):

Guide to EWS throttling and how to handle it is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-throttling-in-exchange

Comment: I saw this page, but would not know how to work with it. If I understood correctly the inbound request are measured over an average 10 seconds. So if I reduce the amount of requests within 10 seconds (build in a time.sleep(3) after every couple emails - could that work?

Comment: It is better to handle throttling responses appropriately as/when you receive them.  For an example of handling most throttling responses (note this isn't comprehensive, and some parts still need improvement), you can take a look at  https://github.com/David-Barrett-MS/PowerShell-EWS-Scripts/blob/master/Legacy/Merge-MailboxFolder.ps1 .

In your case, you also want to revisit the process you are using as it is very resouce intensive.  You may be better with something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ee693003(v=exchg.80)